# distance of a function in Hilbert space from its closed subpace

Tags: real-analysis

I want to find the distance from a function $u\in H$ to a subspace$A$. And $H=L_2(0,1)$ and $A\subset H$ (closed subspace of H) is the subset of functions such that $\int_0^1u(x)dx=0$.

For this I gotta find some $\delta = \inf\| f-y \|$ where $f\in H$ and $y\in A$  . What identity/inequality should i use next and is the answer at the end 0?

Comment: See if you know the answer in 2 or 3 dimensional Euclidean space.  Euclidean spaces are convenient test-beds for Hilbert space phenomena.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is $\int_0^{1}u(x)\, dx$.  Call this number $c$. Note that $|c| =|\int_0^{1} (u-v)| \leq \int_0^{1} |u-v| \leq \|u-v\|$ for any $v \in A$. Hence $|c| \leq \delta$. Now take $v=u-c$. Then $v \in A$. Hence $\delta \leq \|u-v\|=|c|$.

Comment: Thanks, Would you mind explaining why $|c|=|\int^1_0(u-v)|$ isn't $c=\int_0^1u(x)dx$?

Comment: @Jack By definition of $A$, $v \in A$ implies $\int v=0$. Hence $\int (u-v) =\int u -\int v =\int u -0=\int u=c$.